# Network meta-analysis with placebo only comparison

Tags: meta-analysis, consistency, network-meta-analysis

I have a network meta-analysis where all treatment are compared to placebo.

Obviously this is not properly a disconected network but consistency cannot be assessed.

Is it problematic?

Comment: It's called a star network meta-analysis: https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-021-01290-1

Comment: Thanks a lot, couln't find the right denomination. The article is great